# No button Clicking Event in xamarin form inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using swipecards in my xamarin form project.

This is my Xaml code--

```
<swipecards:CardStackView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CardStackView" ItemsSource="{Binding Cards[0]}"    Swiped="CardStackView_Swiped" StartedDragging="CardStackView_dragged"  Margin="20" BackgroundColor="#E0E0E0">
                <swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0,2,0,2" x:Name="layout">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Label Text="{Binding .FullJobName}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" />
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding .CompanyProfImg}" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
                                    <ActivityIndicator BindingContext="{x:Reference MyImage}" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}}"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding .LocationName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleTextStyle}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding .TotalSalary }" Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleTextStyle}" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="Comapny Name" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .CompanyName}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="Key Skills" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .Skills}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="Job Description" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .Description}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView Color="#DCDCDC" WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="2" />

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding .Postedby}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Style="{DynamicResource CaptionStyle}" />
                                <!--<Image x:Name="fb_imageTag" Source="facebooklogo.png">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ReadMore_Clicked" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>-->
                                <Button Text="Delete" Clicked="DeleteClicked"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </swipecards:CardStackView.ItemTemplate>
            </swipecards:CardStackView>
```

The problem is the button is not clicking inside the Data template.
Can you guys please help me what should i do now?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is wrong. Could you show full xaml code, view code behind and your viewmodel

Is `DeleteClicked` is in code behind or in VM?